# Angular js clear tab headers

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular directives for tabbed content.

How do i go about clearing the tab header? the content is cleared but not the headers.

```
  gfApp.directive('myTabs', function() {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
            console.log(scope);
            console.log("LOL");
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            var panes = $scope.panes = [];

            var scope = $scope;

            $scope.select = function(pane) {
                angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                    pane.selected = false;
                });

                if (pane.recommended === true) {
                    console.log(1);
                    pane.selected = true;
                } else {
                    console.log(2);
                    pane.selected = true;
                }
            //console.log($scope.$parent.recommended_shirts);
            };

            this.addPane = function(pane) {
                panes.push(pane);
                console.log(panes.length);
                if (panes.length  == $scope.$parent.recommended_shirts.length) {

                    angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                        if (pane.recommended == 'true') {
                            $scope.select(pane);
                        }
                    });              
                }
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'partial/my-tabs.html'
    };
})
.directive('myPane', function() {
    return {
        require: '^myTabs',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            recommended: '@',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
            tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
        },
        templateUrl: 'partial/my-pane.html'
        };
});
```

the view as below

```
<my-tabs>
    <my-pane title="{{shirt.shirt_size}}{{shirt.star}}" ng-repeat="shirt in recommended_shirts" recommended="{{shirt.recommended}}">
        <div>
            <table ng-class="{selected:shirt.recommended}" style="margin: 5px auto; width: 96%" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="168px">Area</th>
                        <th>Score</th>                                
                    </tr>                                
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--data-title="How to improve a Poor fit score:" data-content="Your Fit Score reflects the accuracy of your measurements based on the inputs you've given us. To improve your score, review your inputs for this particular part of your shirt and ensure that they are correct. Adding more shirts also improves the accuracy of your fit profile." -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>Collar</td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{{shirt.area.collar.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sleeve</td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{{shirt.area.half_shoulder_sleeve.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Chest</td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{{shirt.area.collar.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-hide="shirt.show_more">
                        <td colspan="2" ng-click="shirt.show_more = !shirt.show_more">
                            Show more
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td>Waist</td>
                        <td>
                             <span>{{shirt.area.waist.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                            
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td>Hips</td>
                        <td class="">
                             <span>{{shirt.area.hips.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                            
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td>Length</td>
                        <td>
                             <span>{{shirt.area.length.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td>Shoulder</td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{{shirt.area.shoulder.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td>Biceps</td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{{shirt.area.biceps.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td>Wrist</td>
                        <td>
                             <span>{{shirt.area.wrist.result.result}}<span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                                    
                    <tr ng-show="shirt.show_more">
                        <td colspan="2" ng-click="shirt.show_more = !shirt.show_more">
                            Show less
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </my-pane>
     </my-tabs>
```

Comment: Could you provide your partials as well?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what _clearing tab headers_ means. So it is unclear what you are asking. Also, you use both `pane.recommended == 'true'` and `pane.recommended === true` in your code, I recommend using only `===`.

Comment: sorry for not clear on my question. so what happened was when i clicked on a button it will load for example 3 sets of values into the my-tabs view. so the tabs will have 3 tab headers. when i click out and reload another set of values, the 3 tab headers will not be cleared but the content for the first 3 set is cleared.

Comment: please create a demo in plunker. Much easier to help when console is available